# Grouping items in telerik reporting

Tags: telerik, telerik-reporting

I'm trying to use grouping in the Telerik reporting so that I display a certain value only once. Here's what I'm going for:

[image]

And here's what I'm getting:

[image]

I've tried just about everything I could think of with the grouping. I've moved the Name to the group header, I've moved it all to the group header. Just nothing seems to be going my way with this. Is there a way to actually achieve what I'm trying to do?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't know of a built in way to do this, but you can achieve it with a small amount of code.

If you switch from the designer to code view

```
 private static string LastValue { get; set; }

 public static string SuppressDuplicates(string value)
 {
    if (LastValue == value) return string.Empty;
    LastValue = value;
    return value;
}
```

And then on the designer change your text box from `=Fields.FirstName` to `'= ReportLibrary.ReportName.SuppressDuplicates(Fields.FirstName)` via the expression editor.

It would also be possible to achieve the same thing by adding a handler to the items DataBound event.